# Bad Request response, Jersey 1.17, @FormDataParam and Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0

Tags: java, jax-rs, weblogic, jersey-1.0

I have spent several days solving the following problem.

My simple service works successfully locally on Tomcat 7.0 (JRE7).
But when I delpoy it on Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0 - there is bad request response

My code:

```
@Path("/content-gen")
public class ContentGeneratorAndMergeServlet extends CommonDctmServlet {
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response contentGenerator(@FormDataParam("pdfFile") InputStream pdfFile,
        @FormDataParam("pdfFile") FormDataContentDisposition cdh, @FormDataParam("json") JSONObject js) {
    JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject();
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(responseJSON.toString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();}}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't understand why this does not works on the Weblogic server and works on Tomcat.

Comment: Are you sure it works on Tomcat? I don't see it working even on Tomcat with the JSONObject parameter. Try to just make that parameter a String and just create the JSONObject manually by passing the string to its constructor.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Yes, it behaves the same without JSONObject parameter

Comment: I don’t work much with WebLogic. Maybe Multipart support is something that needs to be enabled through a configuration. You should read the documentation.